# Normal function call in CLASS Type function in swift + sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am working on Swift + SpriteKit
I got problem in CLASS Type function

```
class func cellPurchasedSuccessfullyUpdateLabel()
{
   // ShopScene.cellsLabelUpdates()   // I want call currentCellUpdate function here .. Or Scene name is ShopScene
}

func currentCellUpdate ()
{

}
```

These both function in same scene "ShopScene" . I am unable to call "**currentCellUpdate**" in "**cellPurchasedSuccessfullyUpdateLabel**".
Can any one help me how to access local function in **CLASS type** function.

Answer (score 0):

The point of class methods is that they are not bound to any instance, but the type itself, meaning that you cannot reference instance methods, because there is no instance there. But as a workaround, you can pass in `self` as a parameter of `cellPurchasedSuccessfullyUpdateLabel`, assuming that your code is contained in class `A`:

```
class A {

    class func cellPurchasedSuccessfullyUpdateLabel(instanceOfA: A) {
        instanceOfA.currentCellUpdate()
    }

    func currentCellUpdate () {

    }
}
```

But this approach requires an instance of `A` when you are calling the class method.